# Specifying a function which takes an 'options' objcet with default values

Tags: typescript, function, default-value

I would like to implement a function which takes an `options` object with default values.

I know how to do that, but I want to impose that any field not specified by the user will attain the default value specified in the function header.

Here is what I have so far:

```
function func(options: {x: number; y: string;} = {x: 1, y: "1"}) {
    const x: number = options.x != undefined ? options.x : 1;
    const y: string = options.y != undefined ? options.y : "1";
    console.log(x, y);
}
```

This works fine when I test this function on the output Javascript file:

```
func();
func({});
func({x: 0});
func({y: "2"});
func({x: 3, y: "4"});
```

Which results with:

```
1 '1'
1 '1'
0 '1'
1 '2'
3 '4'
```

However, it feels a little hacky (in particularly, the fact that I need to specify each one of the default values in two different places).

Is there a known design-pattern for this in Typescript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to have default values in two places, you can shorten it up like this:

```
function func({ x = 1, y = "1" }: { x?: number; y?: string; } = {}) {
    console.log(x, y);
}

func();
func({});
func({ x: 0 });
func({ y: "2" });
func({ x: 3, y: "4" });
```

Or even shorter, if you don't need an explicit type:

```
function func({ x = 1, y = "1" } = {}) {
    console.log(x, y);
}
```

Results:

```
1 '1'
1 '1'
0 '1'
1 '2'
3 '4'
```

Comment: I've noticed that it also works when omitting `: { x?: number; y?: string; }`. Is that safe to use then? i.e., are the types inferred from the default values of the object fields, and the question marks inferred from the default value of the object itself?

Comment: Yes, TS automatically infers the parameter types by looking at their default values. If you have a default, the parameter is implicitly assumed to be optional - like `function func(x = 3) {} // func(x?: number): void`

Answer (score 1):

```
const defaults = {
   x: 1, 
   y: "1"
}

function func(options = defaults) {
    const x: number = options.x != undefined ? options.x : 1;
    const y: string = options.y != undefined ? options.y : "1";
    console.log(x, y);
}
```

This will accomplish what you want.

Even more compact:

```
function func(options = { x: 1, y: "1" }) {
    const x: number = options.x != undefined ? options.x : 1;
    const y: string = options.y != undefined ? options.y : "1";
    console.log(x, y);
}
```

Compactest:

```
function func({x,y} = { x: 1, y: "1" }) {
   const _x = x ? x : 1;
   const _y = y ? y : "1";
   console.log(_x, _y);
}
```

Types are inferred by TypeScript from the supplied defaults.

Comment: Your first suggestion is pretty obvious. I could come up with that myself. Your second looks pretty much like my code. I'm not looking to shorten my code, I'm looking to make it correct. Removing types isn't correct as far as I understand the main idea behind Typescript.

Comment: The third one is all you need.

Comment: Though `Types are inferred from the defaults` which you've just added is a useful piece of information (I kinda suspected that after reading your suggestions). Thanks!!